# Chrome doesn't render the right height when combine box-shadow and z-index

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to add a box-shadow and z-index properties to a div. When resizing the window or when a div from above disappear - Chrome not rendering right the height of the div.

Attached codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xexvzz

```
#sidebar {
  background-color: black;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-shadow: 8px 0px 9px #b7b7d4;
}
```

You can click the button to remove the blue part or just try to resize the window.

I expected the green and the black divs will be in the same height but only the green stretch as it should and the black div stays the same.

Thanks.

Comment: add `height: 100%` to your `sidebar` and `page`

Comment: I can't add `height: 100%` because in my website there is an extra top bar above the sidebar so the `height: 100%` make the sidebar exceed the boundaries of the page.
**I've been updated the codepen**